# Parsing mixed value enums (char and int)

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, char, type-conversion

I have an oddball enum where some of the values are `char` and others `int`:

```
public enum VendorType{
    Corporation = 'C',
    Estate = 'E',
    Individual = 'I',
    Partnership = 'P',
    FederalGovernment = 2,
    StateAgencyOrUniversity = 3,
    LocalGovernment = 4,
    OtherGovernment = 5
}
```

I'm yanking in some data from a text file that provides the symbol for this type (ex. `I` or `4`), and I use that to lookup the enum's hard typed value (ex. `VendorType.Individual` and `VendorType.LocalGovernment` respectively).

The code i am using to do this is:

```
var valueFromData = 'C'; // this is being yanked from a File.IO operation.
VendorType type;
Enum.TryParse(valueFromData, true, out type);
```

So far so good when it comes to parsing the `int` values... but when I try to parse the `char` values the `type` variable doesn't parse and is assigned `0`.

---

**Question:** Is it possible to evaluate both `char` and `int` enum values? If so, how?

**Note:** I do not want to use custom attributes for assigning text values like I've seen in some other hack-ish examples online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your enum has `int` as its underlying type. All the values are `int`s - the characters are converted to integers. So `VendorType.Corporation` has the value `(int)'C'` which is 67.

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/qecdc)

To convert a character to a `VendorType` you just need to cast:

```
VendorType type = (VendorType)'C';
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/nXCRp)

---

EDIT: The answer is correct, but I am adding the final code it took to get this working.

```
// this is the model we're building
Vendor vendor = new Vendor(); 

// out value from Enum.TryParse()
VendorType type;

// value is string from File.IO so we parse to char
var typeChar = Char.Parse(value);

// if the char is found in the list, we use the enum out value
// if not we type cast the char (ex. 'C' = 67 = Corporation)
vendor.Type = Enum.TryParse(typeChar.ToString(), true, out type) ? type : (VendorType) typeChar;
```

Comment: Wow... that was a seriously knob question. For whatever reason, I forgot the char assignments were converted to int values... thus why you can't use strings, only char. Thank you Mark.